# Why does my System clipboard listener only work when I add in Thread.sleep(1000)?

Tags: java, clipboard

I have been creating a listener that stays in a loop that constantly listens for clipboard changes. For some weird reason I couldn't get it to work when it went really fast, but as soon as I added a delay of 1000 ms it worked like a charm.

```
public class Chandler extends Thread {
    private String oldString = "";

    private int delay;
    private Clipboard clipboard;
    public Chandler(int delay){
        this.delay = delay;
        this.clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    }

    public void run(){

        while(true){ // Infinite loop to listen to clipboard changed
            try{
                Transferable content = this.clipboard.getContents(this); // Get content from clipboard(text)
                String newString = (String) content.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); // Convert it to String
                if(newString.equals(oldString)){ // If the content on the clipboard stays the same dont print it
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000); // Only after adding this here does the clpboard listener actually work.
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(newString);

                oldString = newString;
            }catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, if it goes too fast it will not grab any updates from the System clipboard. Why is this?

Comment: "Listening" implies an asynchronous notification of some sort - what you're doing is polling.  How do you start your thread?

Comment: It is connected to a JavaFX button which starts it. Should I use async over using a thread for this?

Comment: Well, without the sleep, your thread is probably throttling the CPU and starving the awt thread.

Comment: The listener can't have any time to work because you don't leave your `run()` function to allow him to work. In another structuration of awt methods, your program is split in many methods, and betweens calls the AWT "framework" does, listeners have the time to execute.